# Prove the inequality contains reciprocal fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I would be grateful for any tips or solution for this fractional inequality!
[image]

$(\frac{a}{b})^2+(\frac{b}{c})^2+(\frac{c}{a})^2\geq\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c}$

Comment: Are there restrictions on a,b,c like all are positive? [maybe no need but it might make the proof easier]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not given yet I think the only condition is $a,b,c\ne0$

Comment: Hint: You can transform the inequality using: $x := \frac{a}{b}$ and $y := \frac{b}{c}$. This should simplify it

Comment: On closer look, if you show for positive a,b,c then it follows for nonzero a,b,c with negatives perhaps occuring. This is since the left side is unchanged when signs of a,b,c altered, while the right side only increases on replacing a,b,c with their absolute values.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have already found the solution with the Stiftung Warentest hint. Its hint is interesting because it is a form that we know very well!

Suppose $a, b, c \ne 0$ and let $x = \frac{a}{b}$, $y = \frac{b}{c}$ and $z = \frac{c}{a}$.
Then we get $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = xy + xz + yz$.

Multiplying by $2$ and arranging the terms, we have $(x^2 - 2xy +y^2) + (y^2 - 2yz + z^2) + (z^2 - 2xz + x^2) \geq 0$.

This is equivalent to $(x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z-x)^2 \geq 0$, which is true because every square is greater than $0$.

I hope this solution can help you.